# Svn - get the list of all repos on a server so I can svnsync

Tags: html, svn, svnsync

I'm attempting to create a backup of my client's existing svn repositories, which is publicly available over http.

If possible, I'd like to be able to make new repositories automatically, from any computer, without having to give console access to the server to external parties (i.e. the users could do a `ls` on my svn repo dir)

My problem is that I need to know the list of svn repositories on the server - it isn't a fixed list, since the user will add new repositories over time.

I'm able to list the repositories on an html page via Apache's `mod_dav_svn` module, using the `SVNListParentPath On` directive. I got this page: http://svn.ohwr.org/

My question is: what is the easiest way to obtain a usable list of such repositories? I'll need to parse that list in order to make syncs, probably using shell commands.

Must I parse the HTML with shell commands, or is there a better way to get that list?

Comment: First question: Why are you creating so many repositories? One is enough. Why is the server so old ? (1.4.X? http://svn.ohwr.org). Why not making the backup script on the server which has access to the repositories folder.

Comment: The ohwr site is hosts different software projects (think google projects or github). I need a repository per project. We are using the SVN server that came with the default repositories (ubuntu 8.0.4 LTS). The backups can take place on several external servers. I'd like to avoid having to change the main server every time a new backup server is added, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own solution.

I've set up a cron task that makes an ls on the svn folder and redirects its output to a publicly available file on the server. This file has no html markup, it is a plain text file with just the names of the repositories.

This way, clients can wget that file and iterate over the repository names quite easily.

I'm not very pleased with this implementation; while it works, it its a bit "hacky". I'd rather use something provided by SVN or Apache themselves.

If anyone posts a better solution, I'll accept it. In the meantime, this is my best possible answer.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Comment: Sure: `ls -1 path/to/svn/folders > myfile.txt`